# How to extend folder with another folder in windows 10, in such way that all files in both folders are accessible from one path?

Tags: windows, directory-structure

I have a program that can read only one folder. At different times it needs to look at different folders. I would like to move all same files that exists in all folders to one folder and then 'join' that folder with every folder. Program must see files in 'joined' folder as they are in accessed folder because program can have only one access path. System is Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to merge directories automatically but you can do it with a script to create links in each of the folders you need the shared files in.

I.e. for each target folder create a link for each file in the shared folder.

You can get help with the for command with "FOR /?" in a command window and learn about links here: [The Complete Guide to Creating Symbolic Links (aka Symlinks) on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux)